# Change the snippets location in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I am using visual studio code, and need to place the user snippets in my project repository. How can I change the location of the snippets file to a custom one? I am working on windows 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** [project level snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_project-level-snippets) are now a built-in feature as of the September 2018 release, so this no longer requires a third-party extension.

---

There is currently an open feature request for this ([#8102](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8102)), but you can already get this functionality by using the [Project Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.project-snippets) extension - it lets you place snippets in:

```
.vscode/snippets/<language>.json
```

Answer (score 2):

[added as an answer because really too long for a comment, just adding the details from the updated link in @Gama11's answer above.]

Per the September 2018 update mentioned above:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>, choose "`Preferences: Configure User Snippets`",

then you should see an option like: "`New Snippets for [your workspaceFolder name here]…`"  Choose that and it will create a global snippets file in the `.vscode` folder.

So as long as you have that folder under source control you are set.  Although it is a global snippets file, you can limit the `scope` of each snippet like so:

```
{
  "prefix": myPrefix,
  "body": "...",
  "description": "some description",
  "scope": "javascript,typescript"
}
```

Now those scoped snippet prefixes will not show (as suggestions) in all file types.