# Visual Studio Code Snippets in Source Control

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I would like to check a vscode typescript react snippet file into source code so that these can be distributed to developers.

At the moment, I'm editing a global snippet file under -`[user]/AppData/Romaing/Code/Snippets/typescriptreact.json` -
 so this works great for me locally. It would be even better if I could check this into my application code.

Any suggestions are appreciated -

Cheers

Comment: Looks like this might still be the best answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094206/change-the-snippets-location-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: I assumed that would work and I've tried this but no luck.

Comment: You tried the extension mentioned there?

Comment: You can check an extension.json file in under a .vscode directory in source which is all well and good. You can then reference an extension recommendation so when developers open VSCode, this will be listed as an option for them. 

However, I haven't been able to achieve a checked-in custom snippet file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the snippets location in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094206/change-the-snippets-location-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: See my link above - vscode has implemented a new feature that now does what you want.  I added a bit of a comment there to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check-in a `.vscode/{filename}.code-snippets` file which is interpreted as a JSON file. This can be used to define multi-language user-defined snippets. VSCode has documented it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_language-snippet-scope).